# Downloading & Viewing ePub Books

Tags: ipad, epub, ibooks

I have the following requirements for an iPad App and would like to know if it's possible to implement them:

1. Download ePub books and view them in iPads iBooks reader
2. Install the downloaded book in the devices itunes library, so that they are accessibly from the iBooks applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't import them in iTunes, but in iBooks.
Should be possible.

This should do it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html